# how to tell mypy to include stubfile

Tags: python, mypy

I'm playing around with mypy (version: 0.630) and I'm struggling to get it to see my stub file. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here:

My directory structure looks like this:

```
├── caesar.py
└── stubs
    └── caesar.pyi
```

caesar.py contains some valid python code. caesar.pyi contains the word `bugger`. I expect that when I run mypy I'll get an error. I run mypy like so:

```
export MYPYPATH=${PWD}/stubs
mypy caesar.py
```

There is no output (indicating success). What simple thing am I missing?

-- EDIT --

I then tried a little experiment by adding a few empty **init** files and changing the directory structure:

```
├── caesar
│   ├── caesar.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── mypy.sh
└── stubs
    ├── caesar
    │   ├── caesar.pyi
    │   └── __init__.pyi
    └── __init__.pyi
```

Then tried:

```
export MYPYPATH=${PWD}/stubs
mypy caesar/caesar.py
```

This changed nothing :/

-- EDIT --

mypy.ini now looks like:

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.7
mypy_path=stubs
cache_dir=/dev/null
```

Running mypy like:

```
mypy --config-file mypy.ini caesar.py
```

directory tree:

```
├── caesar.py
├── mypy.ini
├── mypy.sh
└── stubs
    └── caesar.pyi
```

mypy version: 0.630

Comment: @Josh: Thanks but that isn't the problem. mypy simply isn't looking at the stub file that I provided. It doesn't care if I have correct type hints or complete giberish. If I use --strict then it always complains of no stubs because it cant find my stubs regardless. I need it to see the stubs I provide

Comment: Facing the same issue. Neither `MYPYPATH` nor `mypy.ini` helps. Passes trivially without `--strict`, else asks for annotations without looking at the `.pyi` files

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a mypy.ini file, with success:

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.6
mypy_path = /Users/rpg/projects/xplan/yeast-gates-data/stubs
cache_dir = /dev/null
```

I found the `cache_dir` setting was necessary in order to avoid mypy caching type definitions. I wasn't sure it was always refreshing the cache properly.
Your config file looks fine; the only thing I can think of is that the quotes might

Comment: Thanks. The quotes were incorrect. But it still isn't finding my stubs. I've updated the question

Comment: Can you please show a bare minimal working example? I can't get it to work with even a simple file. (example: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9nd1oq/mypy_keeping_type_annotation_separate_from_code/)

Comment: Found the cause and solution here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5520#issuecomment-426371485